# Android Slice is not added to Google Assistant

Tags: android, actions-on-google

I have added shortcuts.xml to my current android application and deployed to the google console within an internal testing track.

My app has been reviewed and approved however my Slice is still not visible in the google assistant.

my static shortcuts work fine as does my google assistant voice capabilities such as OPEN APP FEATURE and GET THING.

why isnt my slice visible in the google assistant?

When I install the slice-viewer.apk it displays my slices fine and they navigate into my app as expected.

Comment: Do you try this https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/slices

Comment: yes, thats the document i followed